# How do I pick the best driver, kart, and glider for a track?

Tags: mario-kart-tour

There are lots of different attributes for each piece of equipment: whether it's a favored track, the quality of the equipment,  its level, its base points, and its special skill.  Some of these are described vaguely, such as "greatly increases points earned" versus simply "increases points earned", so it's difficult to know how much of a difference it makes.

It seems that whether the course is a favored course or not for that equipment makes the most difference, but maybe using something that benefits from jump boosts on a track with a ton of jumps makes a big difference, too. So how should I prioritize these attributes? Assume my only goal is to get the most points possible for the race.

What I'm looking for as an answer is something like,

> Pick a driver in the tier with the most possible items it can get at once, then between those course the one that's the highest level, then choose one with the most base points, and you can ignore the particular special skill it has because doesn't really matter.

except in an order that's actually going to generally give me the most points. Maybe base points don't really matter and the special skill matters a lot, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure that karts/gliders/drivers do not give any statistical advantage, except what is written on the tin.

So MKT being a score-attack game, you will probably want to take the driver/kart/glider in the highest category available (For more items and better combos)

- The driver category gives 1-2-3 items (can only start a frenzy with 3 items)
- The kart category gives combo time (You have longer between actions without breaking combo)
- The glider category gives combo score (actions give more point the higher the combo goes, this boosts that bonus score)

Then in that category you have choices, if you want to take the highest base score or one of the lower ones to grind some points into it. Pretty sure the base score is only that. Taking the one with 50 score higher than the other (in the same category) is only 50 free points at the start of the race, nothing more.

For drivers there's also the special that differs, and for gliders there's the 'more chance of x item' and karts give more points on a specific action, but those are preference, and as I said earlier, I'm pretty sure do not give statistical differences (like more top speed or more acceleration)

Comment: Karts don't increase the chance of a particular item, they give more of a boost and more points for performing some technique (like jumps or slipstreams). So you can't stack the item ability.

Comment: Just checked and yup, i was wrong, so my last paragraph was just completely off. Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure karts and/or drivers DO have stats, they're just not listed for whatever reason.  I find it significantly more difficult to perform precise drifts with certain loadouts, e.g. Bowser Jr's Clown Car.

Comment: Maybe its just the rarity? Like the more rare the kart is the better stat it got?

Comment: I thought the glider category gave you combo time.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on what you want. If you mean prioritize in the same category (kart, driver, and glider), it usually depends on rarity. Here is a chart of the rarities is different items (Normal being the lowest, High-end being the highest):
https://gamepress.gg/sites/default/files/2019-10/mktSpreadsheetInfo_0.PNG

Credits to:
https://gamepress.gg/mario-kart-tour-drivers-karts-and-gliders-guide

Comment: Are you saying I should pick the most rare driver/kart/glider even if the track is a favored one for a less rare driver or the less rare driver is leveled up a lot?

Comment: I’m saying that when pretty evenly leveled up, you should prioritize with rarity